# Combine 4 seperate integers in date form in C

Tags: c

I have a program that reads EMSO(a number that tells you date of birth, state, gender, and some other stuff). It is generated and it is a 13-digit number. The last one is control, first two are day, second two are month, and the next three are the year. I would like the program to tell you your age, by calculating it from the EMSO and current computer date. Here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (void) 
{
unsigned long long int  emso;
int kontrola;
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l;
int x,y;
int kraj;

system("cls");  

printf("Enter your EMSO: ");
while(scanf("%lld",&emso)!=1)fflush(stdin);



    while(emso!=-1){

    kontrola=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    l=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    k=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    j=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    i=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    h=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    g=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    f=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    e=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    d=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    c=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    b=emso%10;
    emso/=10;
    a=emso%10;

    x= (7*a+ 6*b+ 5*c+ 4*d+ 3*e+ 2*f+ 7*g+ 6*h+ 5*i+ 4*j+ 3*k+ 2*l);
    x=x%11;

    if (x!=0){
        x=11-x;     
    }


    kraj=h*10+i;

    if (x==kontrola){
        printf("\n\nEMSO is legitimate!\n");
        if(j==0){
            printf("\nPerson is MALE\n");
        }
            else if (j==5){
                printf("\nPerson in FEMALE\n");
            }


        if (e==9){
            y=1;
        }

        else if (e==0){
            y=2;
        }

        printf("\nDate of birth: %d%d.%d    %d.%d%d%d%d.\n",a,b,c,d,y,e,f,g);   

        if (kraj >=00 && kraj <10){
            printf("\nPerson was born abroad!\n");
        }

        if (kraj>=10 && kraj < 20){
            printf("\nPerson was born in BiH.\n");
        }

        if(kraj >=20 && kraj < 30){
            printf("\nPerson was born in Montenegro.\n");
        }

        if (kraj >= 30 && kraj < 40){
            printf("\nPerson was born in Croatia.\n");
            if (kraj == 33){
                printf("\tPerson was born in Zagreb.\n");
            }
        }

        if (kraj >=40 && kraj < 50){
            printf("\nPerson was born in Macedoniji.\n");
        }

        if (kraj >= 50 && kraj < 60){
            printf("\nPerson was born in Slovenia.\n");
        }

        if (kraj >=70 && kraj < 80){
            printf("\nPerson was born in Srbia.\n");
            if (kraj == 71){
                printf("\tPerson was born in Beogerad.\n");
                }
        }

        if (kraj >=80 && kraj < 90){
            printf("\nPerson was born in Vojvodina.\n");
            if(kraj == 80){
                printf("\tPerson was born in Novi Sad.\n");
                }
        }

        if (kraj >=90 && kraj < 100){
            printf("\nPerson was born in Kosovo.\n");
        }
    }

    if (x!=kontrola){
        printf("\nEMSO is NOT legitimate!\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");  


    printf("Enter your EMSO: ");
    while(scanf("%lld",&emso)!=1)fflush(stdin);
}


return 0;
```

}

In all this mess, `a` & `b` represents day, `cd` is the month and `efg` is for year.

Also, the fflush thing isn't working correctly. It destroys the birth print.

For better understanding, here is my emso: 0701996500037. and here is whar comes out on a normal day:
EMSO is legitimate!

Person is MALE

Date of birth: 07.01.1996.

Person was born in Slovenia.

And I am happy.if I write this: 0701996500037ž, no problem, same output.
But if I enter z0701996500037, no response, like nothing was entered. an if I write 0701u996500037, verification is ok, but all the other is wrong. place and birth are wrong

Comment: @dbaupp, calculating the difference between two dates.

Comment: Careful:  What if your first digit is zero?

Comment: If first digit is zero, that means it is no longer 13-digit, but program responses normally. it means you were born 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in month

Comment: Oh ... you went from right to left.  Never mind.

Comment: You might try using an array `digits[13]` instead of `a` through `l`.  Then you can write the parser as a loop.

Comment: I thought that may have been the way, but the problem is, I dont kow know to proces the array data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time` returns the number of seconds since Epoch. `mktime` returns the number of seconds since Epoch for it's `struct tm *` argument. Thus:

```
struct tm date = { /* fill tm_year, tm_mon, etc. */ };
double seconds_since_date = difftime(time(0), mktime(&date));
```

would give you the amount of passed seconds since date. (This doesn't take timezones into account.)

Comment: How do I print the resoult and how do I define mk_year?

Comment: @user1601731, just convert the seconds into (full) years, and `printf` the value (if you don't know how, it's a good exercise). For information about `struct tm`, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/time.h.html

Answer (score -1):

please check below link , may be this could help you

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/

Comment: Put content here with attribution, not just a link.